# Does the await apply to sequelize.model or .findOne?

Tags: javascript, async-await

```
    const isFound = await sequelize.model(modelName).findOne({
        where: {
          [Sequelize.Op.and]: [
            searchObject,
            {
              deleted_at: {
                [Sequelize.Op.eq]: null,
              },
            },
          ],
        },
      });
```

Which function will get the await call applied to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The member access operators (`.` and `[]`) are ***really*** high precedence. `await` is fairly high, but not that high. (In fact, only the grouping operator [`()`] has higher precedence than member access.) `await` in your code applies to the result of `findOne`.

You can see the precedence and associativity of operators on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence).